# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Tags: sql, python-3.x, cx-oracle

i have Cx_Oracle insert query like below,

```
cur.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD' ")

cur.execute("INSERT INTO table(col A,col B,col C,col D) values (:1,:2,:3,:4)",(lines['col A'],lines['col B'],lines['col C'],lines['col D']))
```

here my column B&C are Date datatype, when i have a values in both they get loaded successfully.

but when i have it has "NULL" or "" it is throwing me the below error.

*> **cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0***

Comment: 1. Are columns B and C are Nullable ?
2. '' is definitely not a date

Comment: 1. yes they are nullable. 
2. tried by passing "NULL" and empty value "". got the same error for both.

Answer (score 0):

A null value must be passed as the value `None` in Python. You cannot use the string value "NULL". You can also frequently use the empty string, which Oracle treats as null as well, but I would use `None` if at all possible.

You can see this if you do the following in SQL*Plus.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYYMMDD';
select to_date('') from dual;     /* works -- returns null */
select to_date('NULL') from dual; /* fails with the error you received */
```

All of the code in your example is not present. It would be helpful to show a complete set of code that demonstrates the problem, including the SQL for creating the table -- assuming that the hints given above are insufficient!